What if you urinate during ghusl bathtub when it is filled up is it valid?
What if you urinate during ghusl bathtub when it is filled up, but before the ghusl your intention was to remove the state of janabah. but when you stand up and done from ghusl and your body is still wet but you whip your body do you become pure? or you stay impure do to the water touching your body
I usually have waswas of this and im not sure if it is a waswasa and do you have to redo the ghusl?

Take a shower or use a bucket and mug to bathe rather than immersing your body in a bathtub, or open the drain and the water inlet to the bathtub when bathing so that the water is continuously flowing. In stagnant water if the odor or color of urine is detectable then you can be certain that you urinated and that makes the water unclean and unusable for bathing.
